# How to combine two columns into one in R?

Tags: r

I have one table with 3 columns

```
A      B     C
1      2     3
2      4     5
3      3     6
```

I have been trying to combine columns into one column.

The output should be

```
x
1
2
3
2
4
3
3
5
6
```

Comment: `data.frame(x = unlist(df), row.names = NULL)` ?

Comment: It works right now. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `unlist` :

```
data.frame(x = unlist(df), row.names = NULL)

#  x
#1 1
#2 2
#3 3
#4 2
#5 4
#6 3
#7 3
#8 5
#9 6
```

Or convert to matrix :

```
data.frame(x = c(as.matrix(df)), row.names = NULL)
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(A = 1:3, B = c(2L, 4L, 3L), C = c(3L, 5L, 6L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```